# Highcharts - 'setState' after 'mouseOut' event

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to program a template for spaghetti plots (see [here](https://python-graph-gallery.com/wp-content/uploads/123_Highlight_a_line.png)). 
Here's [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/javiermarquez/0yg6as52/)

The idea is that only one series should be active. On load, the active series is the one with the highest value at the end. I achieved this effect with chart.events.load:

```
chart: {
  events: {
    //O N   L O A D
    load: function() {
      var chart = this,
        series = chart.series,
        max = findSeriesMax(series),
        points = series[max].points,
        p = points[points.length - 1];

      chart.series.forEach(function(s) {
        s.setState('inactive', true);
      });
      chart.series[max].setState('hover');
      chart.xAxis[0].drawCrosshair(null, p); //IT WORKS :)
      chart.tooltip.refresh(p);
    },
  },
},
```

I would like that on mouseOut the chart "reset" to its original display. However, the series' states are not updated after mouseOut:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    stickyTracking: true,
    events: {
      mouseOut: function() {
        var chart = this.chart,
          series = chart.series,
          max = findSeriesMax(series),
          points = series[max].points,
          p = points[points.length - 1];

        chart.series.forEach(function(s) {
          s.setState('inactive', true);
        });
        chart.series[max].setState('hover');
        chart.xAxis[0].drawCrosshair(null, p); //DOESN'T WORK :(
        chart.tooltip.refresh(p);

      }
    }
  }
},
```

Three questions:

1. Why the series' states are not updated after mouseOut?
2. Is there something like chart.events.mouseOut? Using series.events.mouseOut for reseting the tooltip causes some rapid movements when tracking over the series (even if using stickyTracking: true)
3. Why drawCrosshair(null, p) works on load but not in mouseOut?

Answer (score 0):

I added an event (mouseleave) on the container, and everything is working now:

```
      (function(H) {
        Highcharts.Chart.prototype.callbacks.push(function(chart) {
          H.addEvent(chart.container, 'mouseleave', function() {
              var series = chart.series,
                max = findSeriesMax(series),
                points = series[max].points,
                p = points[points.length - 1];

              chart.series.forEach(function(s) {
                s.setState('inactive', true);
              });
              chart.series[max].setState('hover');
              chart.xAxis[0].drawCrosshair(null, p);
              chart.tooltip.refresh(p);
          });
        });
      }(Highcharts));
```

I'm not sure if this is the best method but it works. See the updated fiddle.

Comment: I think that this solution is much better than this one with using the mouseOut callback because notice that mouseOut function triggers also between switching the series hovering - here you can see what I have in mind: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/a65zgdqb/ and your callback triggers only once - when mouse pointer is outside the chart - that's makes better performance

Comment: Thanks! I thought that setting <stickyTracking: true> would modify the"jumpy" behavior.